# Matrixform ndsolve for mobile robot dynamic equations

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

Error is:

> NDSolve::ndsdtc: The time constraint of 1.` seconds was exceeded
>   trying to solve for derivatives, so the system will be treated as a
>   system of differential-algebraic equations. You can use
>   Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"} to have the system solved
>   as ordinary differential equations

and

> NDSolve::nlnum: "The function value

```
ClearAll[xb, yb, θb, θ1, d2, d3];
m1 = 1;
m2 = 1;
m3 = 1;
lc2 = 1;
lc3 = 1;
l1 = 2;
l2 = 2;

Ix1 = 1;
Iy1 = 1;
Iz1 = 1;
Ix2 = 1;
Iy2 = 1;
Iz2 = 1;
Ix3 = 1;
Iy3 = 1;
Iz3 = 1;

g = 9.81;

b1 = 1;
b2 = 2;
b3 = 1;
b4 = 2;
b5 = 1;
b6 = 2;

c1 = 0;
c2 = 0;
c3 = 0;
c4 = 0;
c5 = 0;
c6 = 0;
M11[t_] := m1 + m2 + m3;
M12[t_] := 0;
M13[t_] := (m2*lc2  *
      Cos[θ1[t]] - (m2 + m3) d2[t] Cos[θ1[t]] + 
     m3*lc3  Sin[θ1[t]] - 
     m3 d3[t] Sin[θ1[t]]) Sin[θb[t]];
M14[t_] := (-lc3 m3 Cos[θ1[t]] + m3* d3[t]* Cos[θ1[t]] +
      m2 lc2  Sin[θ1[t]] - (m2 + m3) d2[
       t] Sin[θ1[t]]) Cos[θb[t]];
M15[t_] := (m2 + m3) Cos[θ1[t]] Cos[θb[t]];
M16[t_] := m3 Cos[θb[t]] Sin[θ1[t]];
M21[t_] := 0;
M22[t_] := m1 + m2 + m3;
M23[t_] := (-m2*
      lc2  Cos[θ1[t]] + (m2 + m3) d2[t] Cos[θ1[t]] - 
     m3*lc3  Sin[θ1[t]] + 
     m3 d3[t] Sin[θ1[t]]) Cos[θb[t]];
M24[t_] := (-lc3 m3 Cos[θ1[t]] + m3 Cos[θ1[t]] d3[t] + 
     lc2 m2 Sin[θ1[t]] - (m2 + m3) d2[
       t] Sin[θ1[t]]) Sin[θb[t]];
M25[t_] := (m2 + m3) Cos[θ1[t]] Sin[θb[t]];
M26[t_] := m3 Sin[θ1[t]] Sin[θb[t]];
M31[t_] := (m2 lc2 Cos[θ1[t]] - (m2 + m3) d2[
       t] Cos[θ1[t]] + m3 lc3 Sin[θ1[t]] - 
     m3 d3[t] Sin[θ1[t]]) Sin[θb[t]];
M32[t_] := 
  Cos[θb[
     t]] (-lc2 m2 Cos[θ1[t]] + (m2 + m3) Cos[θ1[t]] d2[
       t] - lc3 m3 Sin[θ1[t]] + m3 d3[t] Sin[θ1[t]]);
M33[t_] := 
  Iz1 + Iy2 Cos[θ1[t]]^2 + Iz3 Cos[θ1[t]]^2 + 
   m2 Cos[θ1[t]]^2 (lc2 - d2[t])^2 + 
   m3 (Cos[θ1[t]] d2[t] + (-lc3 + d3[t]) Sin[θ1[t]])^2;
M34[t_] := 0;
M35[t_] := 0;
M36[t_] := 
  m3 (-Cos[θb[t]] + Cos[θb[t]]) Sin[θ1[
     t]] (Cos[θ1[t]] d2[
       t] + (-lc3 + d3[t]) Sin[θ1[t]]) Sin[θb[t]];
M41[t_] := 
  Cos[θb[t]] (-lc3 m3 Cos[θ1[t]] + 
     m3 Cos[θ1[t]] d3[t] + 
     lc2 m2 Sin[θ1[t]] - (m2 + m3) d2[t] Sin[θ1[t]]);
M42[t_] := (-lc3 m3 Cos[θ1[t]] + m3 Cos[θ1[t]] d3[t] + 
     lc2 m2 Sin[θ1[t]] - (m2 + m3) d2[
       t] Sin[θ1[t]]) Sin[θb[t]];
M43[t_] := 0;
M44[t_] := 
  Iy3 + Iz2 + lc2^2 m2 + lc3^2 m3 - 
   2 lc2 m2 d2[t] + (m2 + m3) d2[t]^2 - 2 lc3 m3 d3[t] + m3 d3[t]^2;
M45[t_] := m3 (-lc3 + d3[t]);
M46[t_] := 
  m3 (Cos[θ1[t]] Cos[θb[t]] (-Cos[θb[t]] + 
        Cos[θb[t]]) (lc3 - d3[t]) Sin[θ1[t]] - 
     d2[t] (Cos[θ1[t]]^2 + 
        Sin[θ1[t]]^2 (Cos[θb[t]] Cos[θb[t]] + 
           Sin[θb[t]]^2)));
M51[t_] := (m2 + m3) Cos[θ1[t]] Cos[θb[t]];
M52[t_] := (m2 + m3) Cos[θ1[t]] Sin[θb[t]];
M53[t_] := 0;
M54[t_] := m3 (-lc3 + d3[t]);
M55[t_] := m2 + m3;
M56[t_] := 
  m3 Cos[θ1[t]] (Cos[θb[t]] - 
     Cos[θb[t]]) Cos[θb[t]] Sin[θ1[t]];
M61[t_] := m3 Cos[θb[t]] Sin[θ1[t]];
M62[t_] := m3 Sin[θ1[t]] Sin[θb[t]];
M63[t_] := 
  m3 (-Cos[θb[t]] + Cos[θb[t]]) Sin[θ1[
     t]] (Cos[θ1[t]] d2[
       t] + (-lc3 + d3[t]) Sin[θ1[t]]) Sin[θb[t]];
M64[t_] := 
  m3 (Cos[θ1[t]] Cos[θb[t]] (-Cos[θb[t]] + 
        Cos[θb[t]]) (lc3 - d3[t]) Sin[θ1[t]] - 
     d2[t] (Cos[θ1[t]]^2 + 
        Sin[θ1[t]]^2 (Cos[θb[t]] Cos[θb[t]] + 
           Sin[θb[t]]^2)));
M65[t_] := 
  m3 Cos[θ1[t]] (Cos[θb[t]] - 
     Cos[θb[t]]) Cos[θb[t]] Sin[θ1[t]];
M66[t_] := 
  m3 (Cos[θ1[t]]^2 + 
     Sin[θ1[t]]^2 (Cos[θb[t]]^2 + Sin[θb[t]]^2));

M = ({
    {M11[t], M12[t], M13[t], M14[t], M15[t], M16[t]},
    {M21[t], M22[t], M23[t], M24[t], M25[t], M26[t]},
    {M31[t], M32[t], M33[t], M34[t], M35[t], M36[t]},
    {M41[t], M42[t], M43[t], M44[t], M45[t], M46[t]},
    {M51[t], M52[t], M53[t], M54[t], M55[t], M56[t]},
    {M61[t], M62[t], M63[t], M64[t], M65[t], M66[t]}
   });

V1[t_] := 0;
V2[t_] := 0;
V3[t_] := 0;
V4[t_] := 0;
V5[t_] := 0;
V6[t_] := 0;

F1[t_] := 0;
F2[t_] := 0;
τ3[t_] := 0;
τ4[t_] := 0;
F5[t_] := 0;
F6[t_] := 0;

u1[t_] := F1[t] - b1*xb'[t] - c1*Sign[xb'[t]];
u2[t_] := F2[t] - b2*yb'[t] - c2*Sign[yb'[t]];
u3[t_] := τ3[t] - b3*θb'[t] - c3*Sign[θb'[t]];
u4[t_] := τ4[t] - b4*θ1'[t] - c4*Sign[θ1'[t]];
u5[t_] := F5[t] - b5*d2'[t] - c5*Sign[d2'[t]];
u6[t_] := F6[t] - b6*d3'[t] - c6*Sign[d3'[t]];

V = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};
G = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}};

initu = q[0] == Flatten@{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {1}};(* <---N.B.*)
initv = q'[0] == Flatten@{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}};(* <---N.B.*)


q[t_] := {xb[t], yb[t], θb[t], θ1[t], d2[t], d3[t]};


sol = First@
   NDSolve[{Thread[
      M.q''[t] + V + G == {u1[t], u2[t], u3[t], u4[t], u5[t], u6[t]}],
      initu, initv}, q[t], {t, 0, 100}];


Plot[{xb[t] /. sol, 
  yb[t] /. sol, θb[t] /. sol, θ1[t] /. sol, 
  d2[t] /. sol, d3[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: Your code will run faster and, perhaps, be easier to debug, if you do not use `SetDelayed` so much.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't post such a code. Please isolate your problematic chunk first. Anyway.

```
q[t_] := {xb[t], yb[t], θb[t], θ1[t], d2[t], d3[t]};
initu = Thread[q[0] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}];
initv = Thread[q'[0] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}];


jj = Join @@ ({Thread[M.q''[t] + V + G == {u1[t], u2[t], u3[t], u4[t], u5[t], u6[t]}],
             initu, initv}) /. {x_} == y_ :> x == y;
sol = First@NDSolve[jj, q[t], {t, 0, 100}, 
                    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];


Plot[q[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 100}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[q[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Using your code plus the definitions in the question, I still get the error message.  However, if I Solve `jj` for the second derivatives and insert the results into `NDSolve`, I obtain the results in your answer, whether or not I use `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`.  Is it possible that you have omitted something from your answer?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I had two lines permuted. Please ClearAll and try again. Thanks!

Comment: @bbgodfrey Please check that you use the OP's  code only till the `G` definition (including it)

Comment: If one of c1,c2,...c6 be nonzero an error occurs !!! NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at t == 0.`; unable to continue.  why? how can i fix it? i think its for sign function and discontinuity of sign function!!! if c be zero threre is not any error

Comment: i want add a graphics to this code but it didn't respond!!!my graphics code is  `Animate[Graphics[{Thick, Dashed, Red, 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {q[t][[5]]*Cos[q[t][[4]]] /. sol, 
      q[t][[5]]*Sin[q[t][[4]]] /. sol}}]}], {t, 0.1, 100}]`

Comment: @Farshid `Animate[Graphics[
  Line[{{0, 0}, d2[t] {Cos[\[Theta]1[t]], Sin[\[Theta]1[t]]}}] /. 
    sol /. t -> u], {u, 0.1, 100}]` You accumulate questions too fast

Comment: @Belisarius  The computation with your correction works for me now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following works both for the original question and for the case described in the comment about setting one of `c1,c2,...c6` to be nonzero.  Note that the error reported by the OP, `NDSolve::nderr`, does not have very helpful [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NDSolve/nderr.html), and the suggestion to use "StiffnessSwitching" in this case leads to another error, `NDSolve::nodae`, which is unexpected, because `NDSolve` is not being asked to solve a system of differential-algebraic equations.

Because the root cause of all these errors appears to be that `NDSolve` has difficulty solving algebraically for the second derivatives of the dependent variables, we help it by replacing the `NDSolve` line in the question by

```
Thread[ M.q''[t] + V + G == {u1[t], u2[t], u3[t], u4[t], u5[t], u6[t]}];
Simplify[#] & /@ %;
eqs = (Solve[%, {xb''[t], yb''[t], θb''[t], θ1''[t], d2''[t], d3''[t]}] 
    // Flatten) /. Rule -> Equal;
sol = First@NDSolve[{eqs, initu, initv}, q[t], {t, 0, 100}];
```

For `c1 = 1` it gives curves similar to those in the answer by Belisarius (which addressed `c1 = 0`).  For `c6 = 1` instead, it gives modestly different results.

[image]

Incidentally, the `Simplify` above is unnecessary but does reduce a bit the enormous size of `eqs`.